# How to return dictionaries from nested loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I apologize if this is a very basic question, but I built multiple dictionaries using nested loops and I cannot return all the dictionaries, it only returns the first one. I know a part of this is because `return` is in the wrong indentation, but Python will only allow `return data` to be indented there. Is there any way to change this function so it returns all the dictionaries?

```
import urllib.request
import json


def get_url(url):
    text = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
    return text


def display_json(text):
    dictionary = json.loads(text)
    for item in dictionary['items']:
        for article in item['articles']:
            line = (article['article'], article['views'])
            data = dict([line])
            return data


def function(data):
    print(data)


def main():
    url = "https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikiversity/all-access/2018/01/all-days"
    text = get_url(url)
    data = display_json(text)
    function(data)


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *dictionary comprehension*

```
def display_json(text):
    return {
      item['article']:item['views'] for item in 
      json.loads(text)['items'][0]['articles']
    }
```

The JSON is structured as follows:

[image]

There is no need to loop through `items`, b'coz it has only one element. We can just get the first element using `json.loads(text)['items'][0]`. Even if there is more than one item inside `items`, you can still manage it inside the comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

use a generator

```
def display_json(text):
    dictionary = json.loads(text)
    for item in dictionary['items']:
        for article in item['articles']:
            line = (article['article'], article['views'])
            data = dict([line])
            yield data

data = list(display_json(text))
```